# Where does the H2-database draws the most recent database-connections from and adds them to the .h2.server.properties?

Tags: database-connection, h2

When downloading and installing the H2 database on Windows from the [official page](https://www.h2database.com/html/download.html) and starting the H2-database either via the Windows-Start menu or with the `.bat`-file usually located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\bin\` the `.h2.server.properties` are generated as well, as they are supposed to usually in `C:\Users\user\.h2.server.properties`.

Just there seems to be another cache-mechanism for the recent database-connections which are listed in that file, since after deleting H2 and reinstalling it, in the auto-generated file I find connections I do not remember to used them in the past:

```
#H2 Server Properties
webSSL=false
webAllowOthers=false
webPort=8082
10=Generic DB2|com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver|jdbc\:db2\://localhost/test|
...
...
...
```

My question is, whether there is another caching-mechanism, the H2-application uses for those connections.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If this file doesn't exist, H2 writes a hard-coded builtin list of default connection options for various JDBC drivers including the own one. This list can't be configured, but it may be different in different versions of H2. Connection options for third-party drivers are updated from time to time.